# Omitting dollar sign and commas in RegEx in a URL Redirect

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find one RegEx that will accomplish this. I've tried both of the following but it doesn't seem to work. It would seem I'm having trouble with making the comma optional

```
"/cgi-bin/webscr\?(.*?),(.*)" -> https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?$1$2
"/cgi-bin/webscr\?(.*?)" -> https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?$1
```

Example input/output are:

```
http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=me@my-email.com&amount=$300.00&currency_code=USD&item_name=Payment%20for%20invoice%20MS-12345&shipping=0&pbtype=service
```

TO:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=me@my-email.com&amount=300.00&currency_code=USD&item_name=Payment%20for%20invoice%20MS-12345&shipping=0&pbtype=service
```

AND

```
http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=me@my-email.com&amount=$30,000.00&currency_code=USD&item_name=Payment%20for%20invoice%20MS-12345&shipping=0&pbtype=service
```

TO :

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=me@my-email.com&amount=30000.00&currency_code=USD&item_name=Payment%20for%20invoice%20MS-12345&shipping=0&pbtype=service
```

Comment: What language? Why not just use some string sub/replace methods?

Comment: There is no language to access methods or functions to. I am using the WordPress redirection plugin and they allow regex to pattern match the URL for redirection. This is a pure RegEx problem I have. Here is the link to the WordPress plugin if context is needed: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to eliminate all $ and , it would be as easy as:

```
s/[\$,]//g
```

If you wanted to be more sophisticated and ensure that you're only deleting dollar signs followed by a digit or commas preceded by a digit and followed by 3 digits (e.g., 1,234,432.00 ==> 1234432.00) then you can use zero-length assertions:

```
s/(?:(?<=\d),(?=\d{3})|\$(?=\d))//g
```

I don't know what regex engine you're using, but most modern regex engines support look-behind and look-ahead--commonly referred to collectively as look-arounds.  Depending on the implementation, you'd just need to take the search and replace patterns and adapt it to your language/implementation.  The above is a perl search/replace pattern.

Comment: Luv2code, I've seen similar examples of what you have there while researching this issue on Google searches.  Would you mind putting your expression in context with the examples I've listed above and how I would use it to get the intended result? When using your regex examples, they pattern match both the $ and the , ... but how do I include everything else in the string to build the resulting groups to concatenate the redirect?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out!! `/cgi-bin/webscr\?(.*)[\$,](.*)`  Thank you soo much! It works like a charm. I can't believe how many hours it took me trying to figure this out on my own to finally build up the courage to post on stackoverflow. Thank you again!